# looping an array within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make a loop where one value goes up while the second goes down.. I cant figure it out. As far as I can see `checkNumber` counts down correctly, and x and i are incorrect

I know i'm making a silly mistake somewhere but I'm brand new to coding

```js
var checkNumber = 5;
for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < checkNumber; i++) {
    console.log(checkNumber);
    checkNumber = checkNumber - 1;
    console.log("x",x,"i",i);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `incorrect`? What is the output you're expecting?

Comment: Which language is it? Why have you tagged two languages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a single loop and take the difference of the max value and the actual value (minus one, because of the zero based nature) for the second value.

```js
var value = 5,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < value; i++) {
    console.log(i, value - i - 1);
}
```

Comment: this makes sense, i was probably trying to over complicate it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to do this:

```js
var checkNumber = 5;
for (var x = 0; x < checkNumber; x++) {
  for (var i = checkNumber - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(checkNumber);
    console.log("x", x, "i", i);
  }
}
```

This will start `i` at 4 (minus one to avoid index issues if that's what you're looking for, otherwise remove the -1) and go down to 0.

The first loop will count up until 4.

The trick is to use `i--` and set `i` to something higher, then stop the loop with the second condition in the `for`.

Does that make sense?

Comment: thanks for explaining a bit more. i've found this website to not be very easy on beginners and so it's nice to have people like yourself who take the time to help :)

Answer (score 1):

This will make `i` start at 0 and `j` start at 4. While `i` goes up to 4, `j` will go down to 0.

```js
var checkNumber = 5;

for(var i = 0, j = checkNumber - 1; i < checkNumber; i++, j--){
 console.log(i + " " + j);
}
```